# How to get the collection of running packages from SSIS server?

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis

I try to wait until all running packages are finished on SQL Server after I started an SSIS package, but I cannot figure out the correct way to do it. The code I have so far is:

```
var runningPackagesBefore = catalog.Executions.ToList();    

// [..] logic to start the package

while (true)
{
    // get all packages that are new
    catalog.Executions.Refresh();
    var newOperations = catalog.Executions.Except(runningPackagesBefore);

    // get all packages that are new, running and are in the same folder and project as the package
    var runningOperations =
        newOperations.Where(
            operation => operation.FolderName == catalogFolder.Name 
                && operation.ProjectName == project.Name 
                && operation.Status == Operation.ServerOperationStatus.Running);

    if (!runningOperations.Any())
    {
        break;
    }

    // [..] sleep and timeout logic here
}
```

The `catalog.Executions.Refresh()` call causes deadlock problems sometimes. The documentation also says "Do not reference this method directly...".
A refresh is needed because otherwise the executions collection is cached and returns 0 new transactions. And when it runs without deadlocks it returns the amount of running packages correctly.

So I am trying to find a way to see if all packages are finished running. The package I am running is a "master" package that starts multiple other packages. Otherwise I could simply get the Execution ID and get the operation state from the catalog, but that is not possible in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it by recalling the integrationservice and getting a new catalog. This refreshes it automatically:

```
// get all executions for this project that are currently running
var runningPackagesBefore = catalog.Executions.Select(operation => operation.Id).ToList();

// [..] logic to execute the package 

while (true)
{
    var integrationServices = new IntegrationServices(sqlConnection);
    Catalog refreshedCatalog = integrationServices.Catalogs[catalogName];

    // get all packages that are running
    var runningOperations = refreshedCatalog.Executions.Where(
        operation => operation.Status == Operation.ServerOperationStatus.Running);

    // get all packages that are new
    var newRunningOperations = runningOperations.Where(
        operation => !runningPackagesBefore.Contains(operation.Id));

    if (!newRunningOperations.Any())
    {
        break;
    }

    // [..] sleep and timeout logic here
}
```